# Javascript element fade in interval not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, fadein

The code I wrote, I made it in order for a certain div to fade in when my window.pageYOffset is more than 400 and it works weird. To begin with, it fades in but it flashes until the opacity is set to 1.0 and I don't know how to fix it. Please help me I don't know which is my mistake. Here is the code:

```
var navBarVisibility = function () {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 400) {
        var movies = document.getElementById("movies");
        var opacity = 0.1;
        var apparence = function () {
            if (opacity <= 1.0) {
                movies.style.opacity = opacity;
            } else {
                clearInterval(timer2);
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
            opacity += 0.1;
        }
        var timer = window.setInterval(apparence, 70);
    }
}
var timer2 = window.setInterval(navBarVisibility, 1);
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It acts that way because you do not check if the code has already run, so it keeps firing the same event over and over when you are past 400.

You need to cancel timer2 when the offset is past 400.